# how to select an element in html like <p>

Tags: html, css

[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAwMY.png)

In this html code, I would like to select the element with `<p>utilisé 2X</p>`
How can I do ?

Thanks a lot
I have tried on the php code to add a class but I don't find it

```
<?php
while ($query->have_posts())
{
    $query->the_post();

    ?>
    <div class="boxannonces">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

        <p><br /><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        <?php 
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                echo '<p>';
                the_post_thumbnail("small");
                echo '</p>';
            }
        ?>
        <p><?php the_category(); ?></p>
        <p><?php the_tags(); ?></p>
        <p class="date"><small><?php the_date(); ?></small></p>

    </div>

    <hr />
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Please, do not post [pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please do not post images of your code. Paste your code here instead, and show us what you have tried.

Comment: give this element an id or class, and use javascript

Comment: What is "selecting" a paragraph tag (`<p>`) according to you? Please explain what you try to do and what you have tried so far. We help you, but you need to put some effort in asking the question. Googling "select paragraph" returned http://jsfiddle.net/q04jp0qx/2/ But for me this is not the only way to interpret this.

Comment: This is not a right way to ask question refer [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you should learn and ask questions here

Comment: I have tried to ad a class on the php but I don't find the <p>

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how you want to select the HTML code. With CSS so you can style it? You also don't say which `<p>` contains "utilisé 2X".

Just give whichever `<p>` it is a class and refer to it that way.

```
<p class="twice">utilisé 2X</p>


.twice {
   /* CSS stuff */
}
```